# Facebook Integration with ios fails with error message on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

After integrating with facebook when I tap on **continue with FaceBook** button on simulator, it popups this window on simulator..and when I tap on back to home it redirects me to login window and allows me to scroll in facebook insted of redirecting back to my app, and I am not getting any user data with it.[image: this]

Here is steps that I have done

1. Pod installation: **pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'**
2. Added Bundle ID in quickstart guide in developer.facebook
3. Enable Single Sign option is selected to **NO**
4. Added the following code as it is in info.plist
   [image: info.plist]

Added the following code in **AppDelegate**

According to Facebook document we have to **import FacebookCore** in AppDelegate when we Import it we get warning **No such module 'FacebookCore'**

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
                    application,
                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
                )
        return true
    }

func application(
            _ app: UIApplication,
            open url: URL,
            options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
        ) -> Bool {
            ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
                app,
                open: url,
                sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
            )
        }
```

Added the following code in **SceneDelegate**

According to Facebook document we have to **import FacebookCore** in SceneDelegate when we Import it we get warning **No such module 'FacebookCore'**

```
import FBSDKCoreKit  
        
        func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
                guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
                    return
                }
                ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
                    UIApplication.shared,
                    open: url,
                    sourceApplication: nil,
                    annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
                )
            }
```

Added the following code in **ViewController**

According to Facebook document we have to **import FacebookLogin** in ViewController when we Import it we get warning **No such module 'FacebookLogin'**

```
import FBSDKLoginKit
        
        class ViewController: UIViewController, LoginButtonDelegate
                override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()
                    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
                    if let token = AccessToken.current,
                            !token.isExpired {
                        let token = token.tokenString
                        let request = FBSDKLoginKit.GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email,name"], tokenString: token, version: nil, httpMethod: .get)
                        request.start { connecton, result, error in
                            print("\(result)")
                        }
                    } else{
                        let loginButton = FBLoginButton()
                                loginButton.center = view.center
                        loginButton.delegate = self
                        loginButton.permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
                                view.addSubview(loginButton)
                    }
                }
            
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
    let token = result?.token?.tokenString
    let request = FBSDKLoginKit.GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email,name"], tokenString: token, version: nil, httpMethod: .get)
    request.start { connecton, result, error in
        print("\(result)")
    }
}
```

I have tried step 2 from [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/) but I am getting this  error while setting development environment.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've mistaken the Facebook login step.

step 1:- install the below pods

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

step 2:- add necessary facebook credentials (facebook App Id) and `CFBundleURLTypes` in `info.plist` file

[image]

[image]

step 3:- import `FacebookCore` and `FacebookLogin` in your `UIViewController` where you want the Facebook login feature.

call this method for login with facebook.

```
func setupFacebookLogin(){
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logOut()
    loginManager.logIn(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self, handler: { result, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR: Trying to get login results")
        } else if result?.isCancelled != nil {
            print("The token is \(result?.token?.tokenString ?? "")")
            if result?.token?.tokenString != nil {
                print("Logged in")
                let graphRequest: GraphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, name, picture, email, gender, birthday"])
                graphRequest.start {  _, result, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        let data: [String: AnyObject] = result as! [String: AnyObject]
                        print("Facebook user data - ",data)
                }
            } else {
                print("Cancelled")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: do we have to add CLIENT-TOKEN from Settings > Advanced > Client Token...?

Comment: Do I have to remove all the code from viewdidLoad and call this method in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: to commence,  add the Facebook app id, and URL scheme in info.plist file.  then call this method in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Client Token token is not required at all

Comment: I have to remove all my previous code from ViewDidload and call you function ....and can you please specify where I have to call this function in my existing ViewDidload ?

Comment: you can call this on any of the buttons clicks.

Comment: now i am getting warning on simulator: App not setup..this app is still in development mode and you dont have access to it switch to registered test user or ask an app admin for permission.

Comment: go to the Facebook developer console and on the top of the screen there is one toggle button `app development: development.`  make it live.

Comment: when I tap on toggle button it shows : Invalid Privacy Policy URL
You must provide a valid Privacy Policy URL in order take your app Live. Go to Basic Settings and make sure it is valid.

Comment: add any URL it will be live

Comment: I have an LoginButtonDelegate function func loginButton() in my VC...If I removed all the code from func loginButton() and add your code func setupFacebookLogin()..will it work..? you can view that function in question

Comment: can you please help me[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72016301/18362158)